# "Beautiful convergence" in Hejhal, The Selberg Trace Formula

Tags: analytic-number-theory, limits-and-convergence

A simple question:

Hejhal in his volumes on the Selberg Trace formula (particularly volume 2) uses the expression "converges beautifully".

I can't find the definition, even searching the book with google.  My guess is "converges uniformly on compact sets to a holomorphic function".

Does anyone know?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a specific instance?

Comment: Thanks--One example is Volume 2, page 25, Remark 4.11

Comment: Do you think there's a possibility that you're being overly literal here?

Comment: Perhaps Hejhal is seeking for a way of conveying that the series converges in a way that makes it easy to justify whatever calculations he wants to make (perhaps with an implication that the convergence is "better" than some other series come up in the same theory).

Comment: Maybe.  But the phrase is used over and over again (pp. 16, 25, 49, 67, 126, 174, 240, 249, 252, 684, and more)  and since in all these locations, nothing further is specified about the nature of convergence (nothing like "uniform on compact sets") one wonders.